# Partial derivatives for polar coordiantes

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, partial-derivative

I'm given that $\varphi = \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ and I'm asked to show that $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial \varphi}=-r\sin\varphi$$

I've tried to do this and I'm pretty sure this isn't true.

I've said the following:

$$\tan\varphi=\frac{y}{x}$$

$$\sec^2(\varphi) \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}=\frac{-y}{x^2}$$ $$ \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}=-\frac{1}{r}\sin\varphi$$ $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial \varphi}=\frac{-r}{\sin\varphi}$$

Am I wrong or is it the question?

Comment: I got the same answer, so either we both made the same mistake :) or the suggestion in the question isn't right.

Comment: I think you are correct...

Comment: You should start from  $$\begin{cases} x=r\cos\phi \\ y=r\sin \phi\end{cases}$$ That's the true expression of $(x, y)$ as a function of $(r, \phi)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigonometry tells us that the tangent is the ratio between two sides of the triangle, the side opposite to the angle and the side adjacent to the angle. Using this, $\tan(\varphi)=y/x$ tells us that $y$ can be seen as the opposite side, and $x$ the adjacent. That means $y=r\sin(\varphi)$ and $x=r\cos(\varphi)$ where the hypotenuse is $r$ and since it is an independent variable in polar coordinates we don't need to write it as a function of $x$ and $y$. Now doing the derivative on $x$ gives you the expected answer:
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial\varphi}=\frac{\partial (r\cos(\varphi))}{\partial\varphi}=r\frac{\partial\cos(\varphi)}{\partial\varphi}=-r\sin(\varphi)$$

When we change coordinate systems, we consider the variables of one system as dependent and the variables of the other system as independent like this: $x(r,\varphi)$ and $y(r,\varphi)$, or $r(x,y)$ and $\varphi(x,y)$. This is only a convention, since you could use any pair of variables from $x$, $y$, $r$ and $\varphi$ as the dependent and independent variables. Now with that in mind, we see that the partial derivative you are being asked to calculate uses $r$ and $\varphi$ as independent variables, since you are using polar coordinates, and the derivative is taken with respect to $\varphi$. This shows that in that particular partial derivative it is $r$ which is being held constant. But we are using $x(r,\varphi)$ and $y(r,\varphi)$ as independent variables, so consequently, holding $r$ constant and $\varphi$ variable, makes $y=y(\varphi)$, showing that $y$, as a dependent variable, cannot be considered constant (like you did) when we take that derivative holding $r$ constant, since $y$ is now a function of $\varphi$.

Comment: This is very misleading. Of course you can take the partial derivative of $\phi$ with respect to $x$, and the OP even formed the conventional one, in which $y$ is held constant. The problem is in forming the reciprocal and not noticing that the variable held constant remains the same when you do that.

Comment: @joriki Could you expand on what you claim the problem is please?

Comment: @Si.0788: Specifically, the problem is in the incorrect statement "you can't do a partial derivative of $\varphi$ with respect to $x$". You can, and in fact you correctly formed it in your calculation in the question, in the sense that I explicated in my answer -- it just doesn't lead to the desired solution because its reciprocal isn't what you thought it was. More generally speaking, the problem is that Ivan talks about partial derivatives as if you were forced to consider certain variables as functions of certain others and couldn't freely choose which to consider as independent.

Comment: @joriki So because $\sin\theta$ is constant with respect to $x$ this means that the reciprocal is simply itself?

Comment: @Si.0788: I suppose you mean $\sin\varphi$? What does it mean for something to be "constant with respect to $x$"? And what are you referring to as the reciprocal being "simply itself"?

Comment: @joriki Ok, I see what you mean, I meant you --shouldn't-- use this partial derivative because the variable you are assuming to be held constant is actually not constant as you change the independent varible $\varphi$. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: That edit wasn't an improvement. A partial derivative is by definition used when something is a function of more than one variable. So it makes no sense to say that one shouldn't take the partial derivative of $\varphi$ with respect to $x$ because it also depends on $y$; quite the opposite, one can *only* take the partial derivative of something with respect to $x$ if it also depends on one or more other variables.

Comment: But the more subtle problem is that you keep saying things like "is *actually* not constant", as if what's held constant and what isn't were given and not something that you can freely decide. That to my mind is a fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok, I do understand that you can freely choose the dependent and independent variables, and so you can freely choose which you consider constant. I'm having a hard time explaining why maintaining $y$ as constant is not the right way to go about this problem (might be the language). I'll try once more.

Comment: @joriki What about now? Did I manage to get the right message across?

Comment: @IvanLerner: Much clearer :-) ($-1\to+1$)

Comment: @joriki Thanks for the critic, and the +1 :).

Answer (score 4):

This sort of error often arises because of our terrible notation for partial derivatives that fails to indicate what's being held constant. In the context of $x,y$ and $r,\phi$, it's often implicitly understood that these form two pairs of variables that belong together, and then it's assumed that if you form the partial derivative with respect to $r$ you're holding $\phi$ constant and vice versa unless otherwise indicated.

Written in unambiguous notation, what you did is:

$$
\tan\varphi=\frac yx\;,
$$

$$
\def\part#1#2#3{\left.\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}\right|_#3}\part{}xy\tan\varphi=\part{}xy\frac{y}{x}\;,
$$

$$
\sec^2(\varphi)\part\varphi xy=\frac{-y}{x^2}\;,
$$

$$
\part\varphi xy=-\frac1r\sin\varphi\;,
$$

$$
\part x\varphi y=\frac{-r}{\sin\varphi}\;.
$$

Note especially the last step. You can take reciprocals of partial derivatives just like reciprocals of total derivatives, but that doesn't change what's being held constant. The exercise is using the convention mentioned above and is asking for

$$
\part x\phi r\;.
$$

You can't get this as the reciprocal of a single partial derivative without mixing the variable pairs. You can write

$$
\part x\phi r=\left(\part\phi xr\right)^{-1}\;.
$$

But if you want to get it as a reciprocal in terms of the usual partial derivatives that don't mix the variable pairs (I don't know whether that's an efficient way to get it), it has to be as part of the matrix reciprocal

$$
\pmatrix{
\part x\phi r&\part xr\phi\\
\part y\phi r&\part yr\phi
}
=
\pmatrix{
\part\phi xy&\part\phi yx\\
\part rxy&\part ryx
}^{-1}\;,
$$

which you can verify by multiplying the matrices and using the chain rule.

*Update*: I figured it might be helpful to collect all the various partial derivatives we can form here.

We have

\begin{align}
x&=r\cos\varphi\;,\\
y&=r\sin\varphi\;,
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
r&=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\;,\\
\varphi&=\arctan\frac yx\;.
\end{align}

So the "normal" partial derivatives that don't mix the coordinate pairs are

\begin{align}
\part xr\varphi&=\cos\varphi\;,\\
\part x\varphi r&=-r\sin\varphi\;,\\
\part yr\varphi&=\sin\varphi\;,\\
\part y\varphi r&=r\cos\varphi\;,
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\part rxy&=\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\;,\\
\part ryx&=\frac y{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\;,\\
\part\varphi xy&=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\;,\\
\part\varphi yx&=\frac x{x^2+y^2}\;.
\end{align}

From these we can obtain $8$ "mixed" partial derivatives by taking the reciprocals:

\begin{align}
\part rx\varphi&=\frac1{\cos\varphi}\;,\\
\part\varphi xr&=-\frac1{r\sin\varphi}\;,
\end{align}

and so on. There are $8$ more partial derivatives that can't be obtained in this way because one variable of a pair is differentiated with respect to the other, but they can be expressed as products of the other ones:

\begin{align}
\part xyr&=\part x\varphi r\part\varphi yr\\
&=\frac{-r\sin\varphi}{r\cos\varphi}\\
&=-\tan\varphi\;,\\\\
\part xy\varphi&=\part xr\varphi\part ry\varphi\\
&=\frac{\cos\varphi}{\sin\varphi}\\
&=\cot\varphi\;,\\\\
\part r\varphi x&=\part ryx\part y\varphi x\\
&=\frac y{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\frac{x^2+y^2}x\\
&=\frac yx\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\
&=r\tan\varphi\;,\\\\
\part r\varphi y&=\part rxy\part x\varphi y\\
&=\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\frac{x^2+y^2}{-y}\\
&=-\frac xy\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\
&=-r\cot\varphi\;,
\end{align}

and their four reciprocals. And then there are $24$ trivial partial derivatives of the forms

$$
\part uvu=0
$$

and

$$
\part uuv=1\;.
$$

In total, that makes $8+8+8+24=48$ partial derivatives, corresponding to all $4^3=64$ combinations of the variables except for the $16$ of the form

$$
\part uvv
$$

(including the case $u=v$), which make no sense.

Comment: @Si.0788: There's a lot of confusion out there regarding partial derivatives, a lot of it due to the unfortunate ambiguous notation we use for them. I've answered a number of questions based on similar confusions on this site in the past; if you like, you can browse them and see if they help to clarify things -- [here's a search link](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A6622+[partial-derivative]).

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I misinterpreted what you said.

Comment: @Si.0788: I added something on the various partial derivatives that can be formed in this context -- hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

When performing partial derivatives with multiple variables, you should always keep track of the quantity you are holding fixed. The problem seems to want $(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \phi})_r$, while you've computed $(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \phi})_{y=r\sin\phi}$. The subscript indicates what quantity you're holding fixed. Though I must say it seems to be an error on the problem's part.

Comment: Good answer, I agree. The partial derivative formalism can be confusing for exactly the reason you explain here.

Comment: A partial derivative already means that you are holding the other independent variables fixed, that is redundant notation usually used for clarity, since $y$ and $x$ are functions of $r$ and $\varphi$, it is indeed $r$ that is being held constant, but there is no error on the problem.

Comment: Error might have been a bad word to use. I wanted to say 'the problem could have been more explicit'.

Answer (score 0):

It is : $ \tan(φ)=\frac{y}{x} \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{y}{\tan(φ)} \Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial x}{\partial φ} = \frac{\frac{\partial \tan(φ) y}{\partial φ}}{\tan^2(φ)} \Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial x}{\partial φ} =1 + \tan^2(φ)y $ $....$

Comment: You missed a } after frac{y}{\tan{φ}

Comment: @IvanLerner Thanks mate !

Comment: Based upon the answers above, I maintain that the question is poorly worded. It is not clear what depends on what and for that argument, the answer suggested by the OP could also be true.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do calculation with differentials, because unlike usual partial derivative notation, differentials say what they mean. Furthermore, their calculation better parallels single-variable calculus; in particular, recall implicit differentiation.

The question asks for $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \varphi}$. In terms of differentials, this usually means "Compute $\mathrm{d}x$, and substitute $\mathrm{d}\varphi \to 1$ and $\mathrm{d}r \to 0$".

Following your work idea, the part where you go off the rails is easy to get right with differentials:

$$ \tan(\varphi) = \frac{y}{x} $$
$$ \mathrm{d}  \tan(\varphi) = \mathrm{d} \left( \frac{y}{x} \right) $$
$$ \sec^2(\varphi) \mathrm{d} \varphi
= -\frac{y}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x + \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}y $$

In terms of differentials, your error is that you proceeded with $\mathrm{d}y = 0$, but *that's not the intended question*. The intended question asks for $\mathrm{d}r = 0$.

To figure out what effect $\mathrm{d}r = 0$ has, we need to use some of the other identities. For example,

$$ \mathrm{d}y = \mathrm{d}(r \sin(\varphi)) = \sin(\varphi) \mathrm{d} r + r \cos(\varphi) \mathrm{d}\varphi$$

Since we're setting $\mathrm{d}r = 0$ and $\mathrm{d}\varphi = 1$, we can compute $\mathrm{d}y = r \cos(\varphi)$. Substituting into the above simplifies to

$$ \sec^2(\varphi) = -\frac{y}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x + \frac{r}{x} \cos(\varphi) $$

However, taking a cue from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1784002/14972), a shorter path through the algebra is to start with a different identity:

$$ \mathrm{d}x = \mathrm{d}(r \cos(\varphi)) = \cos(\varphi) \mathrm{d}r
- r \sin(\varphi) \mathrm{d} \varphi $$

Now, substituting $\mathrm{d}r \to 0$ and $\mathrm{d}\varphi \to 1$ gives us $-r \sin(\varphi)$, as desired.